# Exapander in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, expander

I want to create an Expanders that will display different configurations.. like color settings , Mail settings.

Let's say there are three expanders ...allign vertically. I want when expander collapse or expand it will shift the next expander. When expander collapse the lower expander will allign next to the uppermost expander..

Like expander can be alligned like as below in collapse mode:
 **Exp1**
 **Exp2**
 **Exp3**

and in exapand mode it will be

### **Exp1**

### Contents

### **Exp2**

Contents of exp2

---

### **Exp3**

### Content of Exp3

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
   <StackPanel>
    <Expander Header="Color">
     <TextBlock Height="30" Text="Color settings"/>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="Layout">
     <TextBlock Height="30" Text="Layout settings"/>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="Mail Settings">
     <TextBlock Height="30" Text="Layout settings"/>
    </Expander>
   </StackPanel>
```